# Moving objects in different coordinate locations and speed

Tags: c#, if-statement, coordinates

Ok I have used c# before but with databases in asap.net and building forms and data driven sites. I am now trying to learn to use it in a animation or game.

I am still experimenting and trying to get to grips with it so bear with me.

So I have two objects (`Ball` & `Target`) that are moving in a windows application when I click a button (I have used time set to false and on click start).

When the two objects pass in each overs space the background changes colour. problem is I am trying to get the `Target` to move left to right rather than one corner to the other.

Can someone show me how to do this with my existing code, Thank you.

**Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int ballspeed;
        int targetspeed;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ballspeed = 4;
            targetspeed = 2;
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int newX, newY, newA, newB;
            newX = Ball.Location.X + ballspeed;
            newY = Ball.Location.Y + ballspeed;
            newA = Target.Location.X + targetspeed;
            newB = Target.Location.Y + targetspeed;
            if (newX > this.Width - Ball.Width)
            {
                ballspeed = -ballspeed;
            }
            if (newX < 0)
            {
                ballspeed = -ballspeed;
            }
            if (Ball.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Target.Bounds))
            {
                this.BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
            else
            {
                this.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
            Ball.Location = new Point(newX, newY);

            if (newA > this.Width - Target.Width)
            {
                targetspeed = -targetspeed;
            }
            if (newA < 0)
            {
                targetspeed = -targetspeed;
            }

            Target.Location = new Point(newA, newB);

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.timer1.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not add a value to the `Y` coordinate:

```
newB = Target.Location.Y;
```

Updating both coordinates will modify the position on both axes. Therefore adding `targetspeed` to both `X` and `Y` will move your `Target` object in both directions by the same amount. The object then moves diagonally. You just need to update the `X` coordinate.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation rather than just answering +1. I will give it a go and accept your answer.